# What can we say about $x^\frac1y$?

Tags: approximation, exponentiation

Is there any way to relate this to something to the power of $y$ e.g.?

Imagine I can only do exponentiation with integer exponents. If $y$ is an integer, I cannot do $\exp$ with $\frac1y$. Is there any way to transform the expression to $\exp$ with $y$? Maybe even just an approximation?

Comment: $\displaystyle x^{(1/y)} = A \implies x = A^y.$

Answer (score 0):

The expression $x^{1/y}$ (or its equivalent $\sqrt[y]{x}$) just means a value $z$ that satisfies equation $z^y = x$.

Plug it in to the [root-finding algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithms) of your choice to get an approximation for $z$.